# Xamarin.Android: Reload MainActivity on RequestedThemeChanged

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-darkmode

We are trying to implement Dark mode after following this [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes). Everything seems to be working except when we try to update the Dark Mode in mobile settings (after the initial launch ). The App in the foreground is not refreshing the dark/light mode changes.

***App.xaml.cs:***

```
 Current.RequestedThemeChanged += (s, args) =>
            {
                Current.UserAppTheme = args.RequestedTheme;
            };
```

The above event is not triggering (e.g second time) when trying to update Dark mode in the Settings page.

I am just curious, is there any workaround to resolve the above issue or any way to refresh the MainActivity on ThemeChanged.

Please confirm if more info is required.

Comment: I did a test with the sample [Xamarin.Forms - Respond to System Theme Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-systemthemesdemo/), but I couldn't reproduce this problem on my device.(android 9) .Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: After following the document I launched the App then Go to settings > Applied dark theme > Switched to the App (did not kill the app) > App Shows in Dark theme. Then keep the App minimized, Go to settings again > switch back to light theme. The minimized app doesn't reflect the System changing light theme now and RequestThemeChanged event doesn't trigger a second time.

Comment: `Then keep the App minimized, Go to settings again > switch back to light theme. The minimized app doesn't reflect the System changing light theme now`  Have you clicked the minimized app and  make it back to front after you changed the dark theme ?

Comment: To listen to the RequestThemeChanged event I need to bring the App upfront and it seems the event is not triggering which in turn does not change the App theme as well.

Comment: Sorry, we couldn't reproduce this problem on my device. What kind of equipment did you use? What is the model and version of the phone?

Answer (score 0):

In doc [Respond to system theme changes / section "React to theme changes"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes#react-to-theme-changes), there is this note:

> Important:
> To respond to theme changes on Android you must include the ConfigChanges.UiMode flag in the Activity attribute of your MainActivity class.

Comment: As I said, I completely followed the doc to implement the Dark mode. It just does not work when we update the system theme e.g second time via settings.